# Android adding containers to a horizonalscollview

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I have to admit my java is rusty and this is my first native Android app. I used Titanium studio a few years ago to build the same app.

I have a HorizontalScroll view outlined in my main_activity.xml and I want to add LinearLayout containers to it with data, each time a user presses a button. So my scroll view will start with nothing, and each button push will add another entry to it.

I tried something with a separate layout for the containers to be added, that use inflator, but then saw indications that I just define it all in the main activity layout. Maybe that was the correct route Here is the pertinent part of my layout

```
<HorfizontalScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/ResultView">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="onShowResult"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/ResultContainer">

    <!--successes-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/success_label"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Success_Label"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false" />
        <TextView
            android:text=""
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Successes"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!--tenss-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/tens_result_label"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Tens_Result_Label"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false" />
        <TextView
            android:text=""
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Tens_Result"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!--ones-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/ones_result_label"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Ones_Result_Label"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false" />
        <TextView
            android:text=""
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Ones_Result"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the code that I started playing with to implement it in my `OnClick` for the button. (the entries themselves will eventually be clickable) This is the only part of the onClick pertinent as the rest is just doing calculations, not creating the view being added.

```
    //create and insert results
    //start by getting the result view we plan to insert to
    HorizontalScrollView resultview = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.ResultView);
    //pull up the container to insert
    LinearLayout resultcontainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ResultContainer);
    //get and set the results

    //add the container to the resultsview
    resultview.addView(resultcontainer);
    resultcontainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

This causes my app to crash and the debug seems to indicate it's something with an `OnClick`, but I wasn't clear. Specifically it looks like the `addview` in the second to last line causes the crash.

I'm fairly certain I'm not understanding something very fundamental and basic about how to do this, but like I said, kinda just diving in and learning as I go.

I also need to edit the text of the `TextView`s in the containers I'm adding, but one thing at a time.

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

So, my question, since apparently there was some confusion. What is the best way to add LinearLayouts to a HorrizontalScrollView, such that I can access and modify TextViews within those LinearLayouts? 
Ideally, I'd like to create the objects being added initially via an XML layout, and not built them entirely programatically. Once created and modified, I'll add them to my HorrizontalScroll View.

Comment: Can you add the code for your click listener and the actual stacktrace?